# Why is my python script crashing on my server?

Tags: python, server

Hey I currently run a python script on my windows server. After 10-24h the script crashes and I don't know why.
Is there an easy opportunity to get to know where its coming from?
I thought about using an IDE, but my server is probably to small and its kind of an overkill.
Is there an opportunity to write the error in a txt file or so when the code crashes?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I want to get to know the specific error

Comment: Can you please show us the code you are running? This way we can assist you on you you can have some error handling.

Answer (score 2):

`python your_script.py > output.log`

will print the output of your python script into a log file. It should help you understand the cause of the crash.

Comment: I have already some code blocks in try/catch. I only want to get the error msg when the hole script crashes. Will this become written in the output.log file?

Comment: yes, it will write all the ouput messages on the log file. So when the script will fail it will write the error message and the line of the code that is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch this error in **try/catch** block, if you suspect what line can cause trouble. If not, maybe you will want to try output method in server console?
Just run script on server and wait for output.

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

The simplest method, but it can work without using an IDE. But before that, try analyzing the code again. Maybe you have a memory leak somewhere?

If you have **try/catch** block, better option is to run script as usual and if some error occur, just print in to file.

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception e:
    #This line opens a log file
    log = open("log.txt", "w")
    log.write('Exception occur - %s' % e)
    log.close()
```

Comment: I have already some code blocks in try/catch. I only want to get the error msg when the hole script crashes. Will this become written in the output.log file?

Comment: I never thought about a memory leak. so that could be. I will inform me more about that!

Comment: If you use **try/catch** block, the only way is to get error message inside code. By printing it or logging to file. Second option is better. You can check it in anwser.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry, by bad. If you want to get errors that **try/catch** didn't catch and script crashed, this method _python script.py > output.txt_ will catch it and write to file